# How to pass and receive back pointer to array of structures?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

My previous question was not a good question therefor I didn't get good answers. Therefor I decided to edit the whole question, I hope it's ok to do so in this forum.

So I have an array of structures and the structure looks as below:

```c
struct patient {
    int pictures[2];
    int personal_number;
    char patient_name[FILE_PATIENT_NAMES + 1];
    int num_of_matches;
};

typedef struct patient Patient;

Patient patientregister[5];
```

I have two functions as down below:

```c
/********* function declaration *********/

Patient *search_patient(Patient patientregister[], int num_of_patients);
Patient *search_by_personaNumber(Patient *matches[],
                                 Patient patientregister[], int num_of_patients);
```

The code starts from `*search_patient` and then goes to `*search_bu_personalNumber`. `*search_patient` has another array of structures declared inside it: `Patient matches[5];` and the idea is to send a pointer of `Patient matches[5];` to `*search_by_personalNumber`. and then get it back to `*search_patient`with the matches the user is searching for. My question is how to send a pointer to an array of structures to another function, use the pointer to fill in the array of structures and send the pointer back to the original function, in my case `*search_patient`?

Comment: Not directly related to your memory management problem, but you'll generally find it easier if you separate I/O from other processing.  Your search functions both prompt for I/O and do searching; you should probably separate these aspects.

Comment: You may also find useful defining a new struct: `struct PatientsRegister` to represent the register of patients (obviously).

You **must** compile asking gcc (assuming you use gcc) to display warnings AND read them.

Comment: My compiler is complaining bitterly about mismatched pointer types.  Yours should be too.  You should fix those problems before submitting a question to SO.  Or, if you can't work out how to fix them, make those the focus of your question.  Show the error messages from compiling the code you show in the question.  (You have are missing header `<stdio.h>` and a definition (`enum` for preference) for `FILE_PATIENT_NAMES`.) You could minimize the code more; you don't need to enter a choice when the only working choice is choice `1`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, thank you for the editing and for your advice about I/O, such these advice are great for a beginner like me :) Some part of the code was in Swedish which I changed to English when posted the question and that maybe caused some mismatching. I'll to edit the code

Comment: @SaifSa: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 2):

You might be confusing your functions for being called `*search_by_personaNumber` and `*search_patient`. They are actually called `search_by_personaNumber` and `search_patient`but return a pointer to a `Patient` struct

The same with `founded_patients`. This array does not contain 10 `Patient` structs,it contains 10 pointers to `Patient` structs.

The main issue is that you cannot return an array from a function. When you try to assign `founded_patients` with the return pointer from `search_by_personaNumber` you will not get what you expect.

Instead do not assign `founded_patients` with the return value. Since it is a pointer already (arrays are pointer to multiple values) when you pass it in `search_by_personaNumber` it will already be assigned with the values.

Answer (score 1):

There is some confusion in your data structure: the member `num_of_matches` has nothing to do in the `Patient` structure. You should instead keep track of the number of patients found (and not *founded*) by returning the number from `search_by_personaNumber`.

Here is a modified version of your code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

/*---- Declarations ----*/
typedef struct patient {
    int pictures[2];
    int personal_number;
    char patient_name[FILE_PATIENT_NAMES + 1];
} Patient;

/* patientregister[] is the original array of structures where the patients' data are stored */
Patient *search_patient(Patient patientregister[], int num_of_structs);
int search_by_personaNumber(Patient *found_patients[], int found_max,
                            Patient patientregister[], int num_of_structs);

/*---- Implementation ----*/
int search_by_personaNumber(Patient *found_patients[], int found_max,
                            Patient patientregister[], int num_of_patients) {
    int personal_nr,
    int matched_patients;

    printf("\nEnter personal number to search for: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &personal_nr) != 1)
        return 0;

    matched_patients = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < num_of_patients && matched_patients < found_max; j++) {
        if (patientregister[j].personal_number == personal_nr) {
            founded_patients[matched_patients] = patientregister[j];
            matched_patients++;
        }
    }
    return matched_patients;
}

Patient *search_patient(Patient patientregister[], int num_of_patients) {

    Patient *found_patients[10];
    int found_count;
    int choice;

    printf("\nSearch by: personal number(1), name(2) of pic ref.(3)? ");
    if (scanf("%d", &choice) != 1)
        return NULL;

    switch (choice) {
      case 1:
        found_count = search_by_personaNumber(found_patients, sizeof(found_patients) / sizeof(found_patients[0]), 
                                              patientregister, num_of_patients);

        /************FOR DEBUGGING: DOWN HERE AM JUST TRYING TO SEE IF I CAN PRINT 
        THE CONTENTS IN found_patients ************/

        printf("\n");
        printf("  %-20s%-9s%-20s", "Personal number", "Name", "Picture reference\n\n");
        printf("------------------------------------------------\n");

        for (int j = 0; j < found_count; j++) {
            printf(" %7d%18s\t\t%d,%d\n",
                   found_patients[j]->personal_number,
                   found_patients[j]->patient_name);
                   found_patients[j]->pictures[0],
                   found_patients[j]->pictures[1]);
        }
        /************END DEBUGGING ************/
        break;
      case 2:
        break;
      case 3:
        break;
      default:
        printf("Invalid search choice!\n");
        break;
    }
}
```

Some important questions you should address now:

- what should be done about invalid input?
- how do you return results from `search_patient`?